# Electric field at the apex of a cone

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, integration

Consider a hollow cone with uniform charge distribution over its surface. When one finds the electric field at its apex it comes out to be an infinite value. However, when a solid cone with uniform charge distribution in its volume is taken and the electric field at its apex is found out it comes out to be a finite value. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate it and see for yourself, as you may know the only difference is that you integrate over a volume and take a density $\rho$. This is what gives it the extra term that makes it converge.

Intuitively, remember that the electric field inside a hollow conductor surface is 0. You can imagine the electrons distributing in the surface in a way to cancel out.

However, at the apex there would be an infinite density of electrons because the area there goes to 0. In a volume, this does not happen as the electric field is not restricted to being 0 inside.

Comment: The OP does not mention a conductor, just a surface or volume with a uniform charge distribution.

Comment: But neither of them are conducting. I am unable to understand your answer clearly.

Comment: It doesn't matter, what's important is uniform charge distribution. In conductors, electrons arrange in a way to keep electric potential =0 inside, and this often results in uniform charge distribution.

Comment: @PandoMM  The charge redistribute to have zero electric field inside and not zero potential...

Comment: you are right sorry i meant constant NOT 0